What does "Axe Power" affect?
I had a Blood Lust Cluster axe I had crafted a while ago, and thought I would upgrade to something better now that I'm in hardmode and have access to better ores and such. As such, I crafted a Cobalt Chainsaw, which is significantly faster. I thought the speed was the only thing that really mattered for axes and chainsaws, but then I noticed that the Cobalt Chainsaw has an Axe Power of 70%, whereas the Blood Lust Cluster (my older axe) has an Axe Power of 75%. Based on this, it sounds like the Blood Lust Cluster would have some sort of advantage over the Cobalt Chainsaw, but I can't actually figure out what Axe Power does. With pickaxes, higher Pickaxe Power is obviously necessary for mining higher-tiered ores, but I haven't noticed anything like this with trees.
What does the Axe Power attribute affect?

It's how much "damage" it deals towards plants.
https://terraria.wiki.gg/wiki/Axe

A tree has 500% hit points and a cactus 170% hit points.

So the Blood Lust Cluster should take down a tree in 7 hits (500/75 = 6 2/3) while the Cobalt Chainsaw takes 8 (500 / 70 = 7 1/7), for example.
